# Access stdout of Conducto Exec node

Tags: jenkins, groovy, conducto

Is there an example I can see of accessing the stdout of an `Exec` node? I am trying to parse `stdout` similarly to Jenkins groovy dsl:

```
tobeparsed = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "myscript.sh")
```

Answer (score 1):

That feature is not available in Conducto. When you want to send data from one node to another, there are a few ways to do so.

In these examples let's try to generate a random number in the first node, and have the second echo it.

- A simple option is to use [co.data](https://www.conducto.com/api/data/) to save the data in the first node, then get it from the second node.

```
import conducto as co
import random

img = co.Image(copy_dir=".")

def first():
    # Generate a random number and save it to co.data,
    # scoped to the current pipeline.
    number = random.random()
    co.data.pipeline.puts("random_number", str(number).encode())
    print(f"Saved random number to co.data. Value: {number}")

def second():
    # Read the value from co.data
    stored = co.data.pipeline.gets("random_number")
    number = float(stored.decode())
    print(f"Read random number from co.data. Value: {number}")

def main() -> co.Serial:
    with co.Serial(image=img) as output:
        output["first"] = co.Exec("python pipeline.py first")
        output["second"] = co.Exec("python pipeline.py second")
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    co.main(default=main)
```

- A more sophisticated way: the first node could be called from a [co.Lazy](https://www.conducto.com/api/pipelines/#lazy-pipeline-creation), and generate the second node once it knows the value.

```
import conducto as co
import random

img = co.Image(copy_dir=".")

def first() -> co.Serial:
    output = co.Serial()
    # Generate a random number and encode it into command
    # of second node
    output["second"] = co.Exec(f"echo {random.random}")
    return output

def main() -> co.Serial:
    return co.Lazy("python pipeline.py first", image=img)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    co.main(default=main)
```

In either case, save that text to a file called `pipeline.py`. Run it with `python pipeline.py` to see the tree it would generate. Run `python pipeline.py --local` to run it on your machine.

There's nothing magical about the name `pipeline.py`, just make sure it matches the commands in the `co.Exec` nodes.